# How to add cross domain contents as Iframe in GWT ? whitelisting is required?

Tags: iframe, gwt, same-origin-policy

there. Am using GWT(2.8) in a production env and we have a requirement to add(vendor service-DOMO reprots) url as an Iframe . I used the below code and its giving me "refused to connect" error in browser, but loading it a new window works fine . Iframe fails due to SOP issue.

```
protected Widget createWidget() {
final Frame frame = new Frame();
frame.setUrl(domoURL);
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
panel.setWidth("100%");
panel.add(frame);
DOM.setStyleAttribute(panel.getElement(), "backgroundColor", "white");
return panel;
}
```

I understand that there is a CSP policy issue and GWT/browser is refusing to load the other domain as an Iframe. How do i handle this case ?
How do  i whitelist the domain (url) am trying to use it anywhere in GWT ?

I tried the below solutions but it did not help

1. Added linkers in module.xml

````
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />
  <add-linker name="xsiframe" />
  <add-linker name="direct_install" />```

 2. Tried overriding the setUrl funtion of iframe.
3.Added csp directives as mentioned in (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src) the http filters.
4.Added meta tag with CSP directives
5.Added CORS policies in tomcat web servers to allow external domains
````

Comment: Why tag this question with [tag:cors]? CORS is only used for lifting some restrictions on cross-origin _network_ access (e.g. one origin sending a request to another), not on cross-origin _object_ access (e.g. iframes on different Web origins).

Comment: Oh Yeah mate! Thanks for mentioning that .